# Background color in cells in NSTableView is 1 pixel off

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am making an OSX app, and for part of it, I am using NSTableView to simulate a "timeline", by putting in a really thin column and then setting the background color. It's fine, except for whatever reason the cell seems to be 1 pixel off whenever the background color changes. Anyone got any ideas? I don't have the reputation to post an image so here's the link: http://imgur.com/PrLdjIV

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: What specific technique have you used for drawing the background color? View-based or `NSCell`-based table view? On what component of the table did you set a background color? (By the way, using a table view for this seems silly. A custom view would be simpler.)

Comment: I have a NSTextField inside the NSTableCellView, and I set the background color for the NSTextField as the color. I'm using a table view because the timeline is supposed to be scroll synchronized with another table view that has images and dates, and because clicking on the timeline at the relevant places is supposed to bring up the image. But if you think I can do that easier with a custom views, I'd be glad to hear what you have to say. :)

Answer (score 0):

An `NSTableCellView` will not necessarily fill a row from edge to edge. Likewise, an `NSTextField` inside such a cell view will not necessarily fill it from edge to edge.

Implement `-tableView:didAddRowView:forRow:` in your table view delegate and set the row view's `backgroundColor`.